# Download Html file instead of render in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

So I am pretty much a django newbie, I do not even know if what I am asking is possible ;-;
So basically what I'm making is a website where users can pass context
Then django populates a template with the context
But instead of rendering the template I want to make the template populated with context available for download

I want to be able to download index.html

I know browsers have a save webpage feature but on mobile the javascript does not work and the icons i got from Google icons also do not load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty easy, your view ends with something like

```
 return render(request,"index.html",context)
```

It should be changed to something like this

```
 from io import StringIO
 from django.http import FileReponse
 response  = render(request,"index.html",context)
 f = io.StringIO(response.content)
 return FileResponse(f, as_attachment = True, filename = "index.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be changed to something like this

```
from io import StringIO
from django.http import FileResponse

response  = render(request,"index.html",context)
file = StringIO(response. Content)
return FileResponse(file, as_attachment = True, filename = "index.html")
```

Or if you are using such `XML` templates you can use it like this:

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import FileResponse

response  = render(request,"index.html",context)
file = BytesIO(response. Content)
return FileResponse(file, as_attachment = True, filename = "index.xml")
```